# Issue with pgfplots \addplot for plotting csv data

Tags: pgfplots

I seem to be having an issue creating a plot from a csv -

I've followed the relevant examples I've found online, but the same thing that works for others doesn't seem to work for me. I keep running into:

Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, could not retireve coolumn 'V' from table etc. etc.

This error is present for both named columns, as well as two Missing \endcsname errors, and two sorry, the request column number in table 'Plot15.csv' does not exsit.

Here is my the relevant section:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Titration},
    xmin=0, xmax=50,
    ymin=0, ymax=14,
    xtick={0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50},
    ytick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14},
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot table [x=V, y=pH, col sep=comma] {Plot15.csv};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Blockquote

Here is what the csv file "Plot15.csv" looks like. It was generated in Excel.

```
V,pH
0.00,1.69
0.19,1.68
0.39,1.68
0.60,1.69
0.81,1.69
0.98,1.70
1.20,1.71
1.43,1.72
```

I know I must be missing something stupid but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Welcome! I cannot reproduce the issue. I produced a minimal working example that completes your code to something that can be compiled, and there is no issue on my updated TeXLive 2019 installation.

Answer (score 1):

Without a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is not possible guess the true problem, beside the excessive axis limits, since this works:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Titration},
    xmin=0, xmax=1.5,
    ymin=1.67, ymax=1.73,
    xtick={0,.5,1,1.5},
    ytick={1.68,1.7,1.72},
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed]
\addplot table [x=V, y=pH, col sep=comma]{Plot15.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```